# How to make changed_when work in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a script using the command module on a Jenkins server. The script is written in such a way that it should return 0 if not making any configuration changes and the Ansible task should not be changed.

Here is the code:

```
  - name: Script to run
    command: java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy "{{ jenkins_home }}/userContent/script.groovy"
    register: return_code
    changed_when: return_code.stdout != 0
```

But the above code behaves is always showing as changed.

The Ansible output:

> TASK [jenkins : Script to run] ********************************
>
> changed: [test] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["java", "-jar", "/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar", "-s", "http://localhost:8080", "groovy", "/var/lib/jenkins/userContent/script.groovy"], "delta": "0:00:01.547098", "end": "2017-02-06 15:31:05.989134", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-02-06 15:31:04.442036", "stderr": "[WARN] Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding as anonymous", "stdout": "0", "stdout_lines": ["0"], "warnings": []}

Comment: By "*return 0*" you mean it prints `0` or that the return code is 0?

Comment: Try return_code.rc != 0.

Comment: I already tried that but it is not working.

Comment: @techraf by return 0 means I have the implementation in script that if nothing chnages return 0;

Comment: Do you have logs?

Comment: @andyhky updated question with ansible verbose output

Comment: Try return_code.stdout != '0'

Comment: Thanks @andyhky It worked but I am unable to understand why it needs the exit code in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the `stdout` value with a string instead of an integer:

```
- name: Script to run
  command: java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy "{{ jenkins_home }}/userContent/script.groovy"
  register: script_call
  changed_when: script_call.stdout != "0"
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate why I need to put 0 in quotes. That will be a big help.

Comment: It's already written in the first sentence of the answer. Which word is unclear to you?

Comment: I understand your answer what is unclear to me is the concept as it should be based on the exit code which is 0 not "0"

Comment: But I asked you specifically what was your intention, you added a log clearly showing `"stdout": "0"` which is not an exit code, but a standard output. If you want to check for return code, you should use `script_call.rc != 0`.